# Как прилепить к товару надпись (span) "Акция!" если заполнено поле цены распродажи (sale_price)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Вопрос касается вариативного товара!
Для простого товара делается следующим кодом:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function() {
 global $product; 
 $akc = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
 if ( $akc > 0 ) {
 echo '<span class="onsale soldout">Акция!</span>';
 }
});
```

Но не понятно как получить значение всех полей именно с ценой распродажи **(sale_price)** для вариаций?
Пробовал взять из **$prices_array**, но тщетно.

**UPDATE**

Получить цену таким образом тоже не вышло:

```
if ( 'product_variation' === $_this->post_type ) {
        $data            = (object) $_this->get_data();
        $variation_price = $data->price;
        $product_id       = $data->parent_id;
        $variation_sale_price = get_sale_price( $variation_price, $product_id );
        var_dump($variation_sale_price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Смог получить минимальную цену вариации, но как выделить именно **'sale_price'**?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function($price) {
 global $product; 

if($product->product_type == 'variable') {
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true ) );

 if ( !empty ($prices)  ) {
 echo '<span class="onsale soldout">Акция!</span>';
 }
}});
```

**UPDATE**

Вопрос закрыт, разобрался, неужели сложно было подсказать неопытному дурачку что нужно сделать так?)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function($price) {
 global $product; 

if($product->product_type == 'variable') {

    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true )); 
    $prices2 = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ));

    if ($prices !== $prices2){

 echo '<span class="onsale soldout">Акция!</span>';
 }
}});
```

Comment: Обижаться не надо. У людей не всегда есть время отвечать на вопросы. Здесь же не платная служба поддержки с жёстко заданным временем реагирования.

Comment: да я понимаю, никаких обид, тем более по отношению к вам, вам только благодарность)